# URL Button Lookup Field Population Cannot Handle Contact with Same Name

Tags: lookup, button, url

I have been creating a URL button to create records and prepopulate the records with information.

There is a lookup field to the Contact object which is giving me issues as there are multiple Contacts that have the same name (John Smith, common names, etc.).

The lookup field population fails stating that more than one record is found with the name.

Why is this occurring? The URL logic for lookup fields requires both the Name and the unique record Id, this should indicate to Salesforce which record is desired.

/a0c/e?CF00Na000000BR1xN_Ikid={!Account.Id}&CF00Na000000BR1xN={!Account.Name}&CF00Na000000BR1xI={!Contact.Name}&CF00Na000000BR1xI_Ikid={!Contact.Id}

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Newbie mistake... used an "I" instead of a "L" in lkid.

Cheers!

Mercury86